# JAVA Tic Tac Toe AI

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

So I designed a GUI Tic Tac Toe game in Java that works if two players were to play against one another. However, I'm trying to implement an "AI mode". So far everything is working as expected except the AI mode. What happens is that the AI makes predictable moves and doesn't correctly block the user from winning (which is my goal as of now). The way I have it set up is that if early on in the game (since it's technically impossible to have a winning move if you have only one spot marked), the AI will randomly pick a spot. Other wise, if the user has a winning move, the AI will simply prevent the user from winning. The problem is that the AI will pick spots not even close to preventing the user from winning.

The GUI is designed using a 2-dimensional array and using getText() to know which player owns the tile. It is also set up so that the user is always "X", while the AI or any opponent is "O". I have an inner class AI, that has a checkBoard method and a makeMoves method shown below. I also experimented with a second makeMoves method which is also listed below. Any ideas or suggestions to get this to go? All help is appreciated.

The actionListener for the buttons:

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        private AI ai = new AI();
        private int x;
        private int y;
        public ButtonListener(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                if (button.getText() == "") {
                    if (turn) {
                        button.setText("X");
                        turn = false;
                        if (checkWinner(x,y)) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Winner!");
                            refresh();
                        }
                    } else if (isComputerPlaying)  {
                        ai.getMoves();
                        ai.checkBoard();

                        } else {
                            button.setText("O");
                            turn = true;
                            if (checkWinner(x,y)) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Winner!");
                                refresh();
                        }
                        }
                    } 
                }
        }
```

AI inner class:

```
public class AI {
            //----------------------------------------------
            //Uses getMoves method and marks a spot on the board
            //----------------------------------------------



            public void checkBoard() {
                if (!turn) {
                    if (getMoves().isEmpty()) {
                        turn = true;
                        int x = getRandom();
                        int y = getRandom();
                        buttons[x][y].setText(toString());
                        checkWinner(x,y);

                    } else {
                        if (buttons[getMoves().get(0)][getMoves().get(1)].getText() == "") {
                            buttons[getMoves().get(0)][getMoves().get(1)].setText(toString());
                        } else {
                            buttons[getMoves().get(0)][getMoves().get(1)].setText(toString());
                        }

                        getMoves().removeAll(getMoves());
                        turn = true;
                    }

                }
            }


            public int getRandom() {
                int random = Math.random() > .75 ? 2: Math.random() <= .50 ? 1 : Math.random() <= .25 ? 1 : null;
                return random;
            }

            //----------------------------------------------
            //Determine all possible win moves by the user
            //----------------------------------------------


            public ArrayList<Integer> getMoves() {
                ArrayList<Integer> getMoves = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                        if (buttons[x][y].getText() == "X") {
                            if (x < 2 && y < 2) {
                                if (checkWinner(x+1,y+1)) {
                                    getMoves.add(x+1);
                                    getMoves.add(y+1);
                                } else if (checkWinner(x+1,y)) {
                                    getMoves.add(x+1);
                                    getMoves.add(y);
                                } else if (checkWinner(x,y+1)) {
                                    getMoves.add(x);
                                    getMoves.add(y+1);
                                }
                            } else if(x > 0 && y > 0) {
                                if (checkWinner(x-1,y-1)) {
                                    getMoves.add(x-1);
                                    getMoves.add(y-1);
                                } else if (checkWinner(x-1,y)) {
                                    getMoves.add(x-1);
                                    getMoves.add(y);
                                } else if (checkWinner(x,y-1)) {
                                    getMoves.add(x);
                                    getMoves.add(y-1);
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }

                return getMoves;
            }






            public String toString() {
                return "O";
            }
        }
```

checkWinner class, which determines if a player has won using a defined sequence:

```
public boolean checkWinner(int x, int y) {
            if (buttons[0][y].getText() == buttons[1][y].getText() && buttons[2][y].getText() == buttons[1][y].getText()) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (buttons[x][0].getText() == buttons[x][1].getText() && buttons[x][2].getText() == buttons[x][0].getText()) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (x == y) {
                return buttons[0][0].getText() == buttons[1][1].getText() && buttons[0][0].getText() == buttons[2][2].getText();
            }
            else if ((x == 0 && y == 2) || (x==2 && y==0) || x==y) {
                return buttons[2][0].getText() == buttons[1][1].getText() && buttons[2][0].getText() == buttons[0][2].getText();
            }


        return false;

    }
```

And lastly, the experimental getMoves method, renamed as getMoves2. For some weird reason, it would erase already placed moves:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getMoves2(int x, int y) {
                ArrayList<Integer> getMoves2 = new ArrayList<>();
                if (x < 2 && y < 2) {
                    buttons[x+1][y+1].setText("X");
                    buttons[x+1][y].setText("X");
                    buttons[x][y+1].setText("X");
                    if (checkWinner(x+1,y+1)) {
                        getMoves2.add(x+1);
                        getMoves2.add(y+1);
                    } else if (checkWinner(x+1,y)) {;
                        getMoves2.add(x+1); 
                        getMoves2.add(y);
                    } else if (checkWinner(x,y+1)) {
                        getMoves2.add(x);
                        getMoves2.add(y+1);
                    }

                    buttons[x+1][y+1].setText("");
                    buttons[x+1][y].setText("");
                    buttons[x][y+1].setText("");
                } else if(x > 0 && y > 0) {
                    buttons[x-1][y-1].setText("X");
                    buttons[x-1][y].setText("X");
                    buttons[x][y-1].setText("X");
                    if (checkWinner(x-1,y-1)) {
                        getMoves2.add(x-1);
                        getMoves2.add(y-1);
                    } else if (checkWinner(x-1,y)) {
                        getMoves2.add(x-1);
                        getMoves2.add(y);
                    } else if (checkWinner(x,y-1)) {
                        getMoves2.add(x);
                        getMoves2.add(y-1);
                    }

                    buttons[x-1][y-1].setText("");
                    buttons[x-1][y].setText("");
                    buttons[x][y-1].setText("");
                }
                return getMoves2;
            }
```

Thank you again for all help!

Comment: Look into Minimax algorithms. http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question as it stands does not live up to StackOverflow's question standards (in particular, your question asks for debugging help without demonstrating effort has been put into isolating the issue). Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for advice on how to structure questions better.

Comment: Please add comments to your code. If not for us, then for yourself.

Comment: I have comments there for myself